# What's a good pixelation algorithm in C# .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing

What is a good algorithm for pixelating an image in C# .NET?

Comment: What do you want "pixelating" to mean?

Comment: How fast do you need this to be? Good ol' shrink & expand works great, but is pretty slow. If you only have to do this once, don't get fancy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple, yet unefficient solution would be to resize to a smaller size, then resize back using pixel duplication.

A better solution would be (pseudo-code):
(Time O(n), Additional space (besides mutable source image): O(1))

```
// Pixelize in x axis (choose a whole k s.t. 1 <= k <= Width)
var sum = Pixel[0, 0];
for (y = 0; y < Height; y++)
{
    for (x = 0; x < Width + 1; x++)
    {
        if (x % k == 0)
        {
            sum /= k;
            for (xl = Max(0, x-k); xl < x; xl++)
                Pixel[y, xl] = sum;
            sum = 0;
        }
        if (x == Width)
            break;
        sum += Pixel[y, x];
    }
}

// Now do the same in the y axis
// (make sure to keep y the outer loop - for better performance)

// If your image has more than one channel, then then Pixel should be a struct.
```

Answer (score 1):

The guy over at [this forum](http://www.talkphp.com/script-giveaway/3620-pixelate-algorithm-using-gd.html) has a pretty good algorithm. It works by taking the average of all of the colors in each "block."

I just used his implementation in C#/GDI+ today:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

/// <summary>
/// Applies a pixelation effect to an image.
/// </summary>
[SuppressMessage(
    "Microsoft.Naming",
    "CA1704",
    Justification = "'Pixelate' is a word in my book.")]
public class PixelateEffect : EffectBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the block size, in pixels.
    /// </summary>
    private int blockSize = 10;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the block size, in pixels.
    /// </summary>
    public int BlockSize
    {
        get
        {
            return this.blockSize;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value <= 1)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value");
            }

            this.blockSize = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Applies the effect by rendering it onto the target bitmap.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">The source bitmap.</param>
    /// <param name="target">The target bitmap.</param>
    public override void DrawImage(Bitmap source, Bitmap target)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        }

        if (target == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("target");
        }

        if (source.Size != target.Size)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The source bitmap and the target bitmap must be the same size.");
        }

        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(target))
        {
            graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;

            for (int x = 0; x < source.Width; x += this.BlockSize)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < source.Height; y += this.BlockSize)
                {
                    var sums = new Sums();

                    for (int xx = 0; xx < this.BlockSize; ++xx)
                    {
                        for (int yy = 0; yy < this.BlockSize; ++yy)
                        {
                            if (x + xx >= source.Width || y + yy >= source.Height)
                            {
                                continue;
                            }

                            var color = source.GetPixel(x + xx, y + yy);
                            sums.A += color.A;
                            sums.R += color.R;
                            sums.G += color.G;
                            sums.B += color.B;
                            sums.T++;
                        }
                    }

                    var average = Color.FromArgb(
                        sums.A / sums.T,
                        sums.R / sums.T,
                        sums.G / sums.T,
                        sums.B / sums.T);

                    using (var brush = new SolidBrush(average))
                    {
                        graphics.FillRectangle(brush, x, y, (x + this.BlockSize), (y + this.BlockSize));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A structure that holds sums for color averaging.
    /// </summary>
    private struct Sums
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the alpha component.
        /// </summary>
        public int A
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the red component.
        /// </summary>
        public int R
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the blue component.
        /// </summary>
        public int B
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the green component.
        /// </summary>
        public int G
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the total count.
        /// </summary>
        public int T
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Caveat emptor, works on my machine, & etc.

Answer (score -1):

While I don't know of a well know algorithm for this, I did have to write something similar. The technique I used was pretty simple, but I am thinking not very efficient for large images. Basically I would take the image and do color averaging in 5 (or howerver big you want) pixel blocks and then make all those pixels the same color. You could speed this up by doing the average on just the diagonal pixels which would save a lot of cycles but be less accurate.